# PhpStorm does not recognise services defined in yml files

Tags: phpstorm, symfony

According to [Symfony Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) documentation PhpStorm should be able to recognise services when using service container:

> - References for services in ContainerInterface::get()
> - Detect ContainerInterface::get() result type

I have PhpStorm 2016.3.2, Symfony plugin 0.13.134, Symfony plugin enabled for my project, however PhpStorm is unable to recognise services defined in yml file in my custom Symfony bundle.

When referencing my services in yml files with `@my.service.id` IDE raises a warning: "Missing service". The same problem occurs when requesting services with `ContainerInterface::get('my.service.id')`.

All works fine for services defined in Symfony core, but fails to work when it comes to my own services.

Apparently IDE is able to recognise event listeners defined inside bundle's `src/[Bundle]/Resource/config/event_listeners.yml` without a problem, yet it can't recognise services defined in `src/[Bundle]/Resource/config/services.yml`

Comment: AFAIK this functionality is provided purely by Symfony plugin .. so you have to ask such question at their Issue Tracker (example of existing recently created ticket: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/845)

Answer (score 1):

Check on `Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Symofony` that the configuration paths are correct.

Comment: `app` is `app` and `web` is `web` - all seems fine. `UrlGenerator` is deprecated, so irrelevant and there are no translations.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with PhpStrom 2018.2.2 and Symfony plugin v0.16.165
I use .yml file and find out that if there is double quotes in class property - PhpStorm is unable to recognise services, and if single quotes or without - all works

Not work

```
some.service:
    class: "App\SomeService"
    arguments: ["@argument"]
```

Work

```
some.service:
    class: 'App\SomeService'
    arguments: ["@argument"]
```

Work too

```
some.service:
    class: App\SomeService
    arguments: ["@argument"]
```

Also in documentation all classes are without quotes for any version of Symfony
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html